# Log parsing using RegEx

Tags: python, regex, logging, logparser

I want to parse the following logs in particular classes.

```
2019-11-14T04:24:04.072Z  INFO MessagingObjectFactoryImpl-4-2 ExporterLastAckServiceImpl - - [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Found exporter with elaId = Node#a3844284-e626-11e9-a87b-005056bcc0c6#AggSvc-L2-Bridging, returning lastAck = 16507 
2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z  INFO ActivityEventRecovery-1 ActivityCacheManager - - [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Handling activity 92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1 
2019-11-14T04:23:08.362Z  DEBUG ActivityEventRecovery-1 ActivityCacheManager - - [nsx@6876 comp="nsx-manager" level="INFO" subcomp="manager"] Handling activity 92d6a146-fa12-4889-a0ff-441087e047d0 completion event for 1
```

I tried

```
(?<timestamp>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d\dZ)\s+(?<level>INFO|WARN|DEBUG|ERROR|FATAL|TRACE)\s+(?<text>.*?\s.*?)\-\s+\-\s\[(?<class>.*?)\]\s+(?<Message>.*? |\Z)
```

I am getting everything with this except Message class.
How should I write Message class Regex?

Here's the link https://regex101.com/r/LJnVrS/86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*?` will match as few characters as possible, until you get to a space. Because it looks like the matches all end at the end of a line, instead, just continue matching whatever you can until you get to the end of the line. Remove the `s` flag, and use:

```
(?<Message>.*)
```

(no need for `\Z`)

https://regex101.com/r/LJnVrS/87